# Dart: how to use json_serializable library to create different subclasses from the json input

Tags: json, dart, json-serializable

[UML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r4wsv.png)

[image]

I have to serialize json in order to create specific subclass from the Enum which is an attribute of one class that contains the abstract class target

```
class Test {
  Outcome outcome;
  TestType type;
}

abstract class Outcome {
  String attribute;
}

class PackageOutcome extends Outcome {
  String packageAttribute;
}

class FlexibilityOutcome extends Outcome {
  String flexibilityAttribute;
}
```

Outcome doesn't have factory methods to serialize json, but PackageOutcome and FlexibilityOutcome have it.

in factory method `Test.toJson()` if I have a specific type of Enum TestType I crate PackageOutcome and if I've another type I create `FlexibilityOutcome` as Outcome of Test.

you can do this with json_serializable?
There are some tutorials that explain how to do that?

Comment: hi, did u find a solution for this? I need help with this also.